# Is there any way I can download MCPE on my PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering if there was any way to download MCPE to my PC (Windows10), I have already bought it.

Comment: Can someone explain what is unclear about this question? user234382 has minecaft pocket edition and wants to download it onto his/her PC, which runs windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

Log into [Minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/) using the credentials for your MCPE game, and download a copy of "Minecraft Windows 10 Edition".

MCPE is discontinued currently - its successor is Bedrock Edition, a multiplatform version of Minecraft, in many variants for different platforms but sharing the same account/purchase, and enabling cross-play between them all - if you purchased a Bedrock Edition (or the MCPE predecessor) you can use it on any supported platform (though play on only one at a time). The different platform variants of Bedrock have their own names; "Minecraft Windows 10 Edition" is the name of the Windows 10 variant.